# "Queueing" or "Queuing"

Tags: meaning, orthography

Which spelling is better, *queueing* or *queuing*? Both words seem to mean the same, but there are two different spellings. My context is:

> Queueing Latency

versus

> Queuing Latency

If both spellings are applicable, when do I use which one of them?

Comment: The shorter spelling has rapidly [taken the ascendancy](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=queueing%2Cqueuing&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in recent decades, and I don't think this is particularly a US or UK thing, so I'd advise going with it if you want to seem more up-to-date.

Comment: You have to use Queueing as it is the word with the longest consecutive use of vowels.

Comment: I know! Doesnt the '*ueuei*' fascinate you?!

Comment: The longer form is [preferred](http://xkcd.com/853/).

Comment: At MIT, I was taught that the MIT spelling is "queueing"---after all who can resist a word with five vowels in a row.

Comment: @user52278 It isn't the longest consecutive use of vowels though. That is 'euouae' which has the added bonus of being the longest word consisting entirely of vowels. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euouae. Although a mnemonic, it is a valid Scrabble word and is in some dictionaries.

Comment: @darrenp I would hardly count an ancient Latin abbreviation nobody has ever heard of as a more valid record holder than a word I say on a somewhat regular basis (i.e. "queueing"). Obscure pun intended.

Comment: @Dan I completely agree that if you are only counting words that are in common usage then 'queueing' is an excellent example and presumably the record. But that wasn't what user52278 claimed. They said it is 'the' word with the longest consecutive use of vowels. ;-)

Comment: @user52278's comment is the correct answer

Comment: Other common(ish) words with 5 consecutive vowels: "miaoued" (and "miaouing") and "cooeeing".

Comment: Note that there are going to be people (how many?) who spell it _cueing_.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Both occur and there's no difference in meaning.

Comment: But which one is more popular/winning?

Answer (score 61):

Just in case if anyone is wondering which one is more popular: (Queuing!)

[image: Results from Google Ngram Viewer]

Comment: ty for your work (i've +1-ed it), any idea if we could expand the end date? for me it seems to display 2008.

Comment: @p1100i the Google Ngram viewer (which was used to generate the graph; reproduce it [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=queueing%2Cqueuing&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cqueueing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bqueueing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQueueing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQUEUEING%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cqueuing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bqueuing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQueuing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQUEUING%3B%2Cc0)) currently only shows data up to 2008.

Comment: I wonder what caused the revolution in the 1990s